# PCLinuxOS install without usb keyboard at bootloader

Tags: system-installation, livecd

I have a PCLinuxOS Live CD in a very old computer (emachines etower 500i), and have managed to boot into the Live CD. The USB keyboard does not work in the bootloader, so it is impossible to select the "Install" option. I see from `isolinux.cfg` that the install is activated as an option to the kernel (`install` on the kernel command line). How can I get PCLinuxOS installed from the live cd (by activating the installer, or by manually copying over the files, with `cp` or `dd`)?

Answer (score 0):

Boot the Live CD and then select the installer from the menu.

Comment: I booted with the install disk, into Live mode. It is impossible to select install from the menu because the USB keyboard drivers do not appear to be installed in isolinux.

Comment: No, I meant boot the live environment and then look for the installer in the respective desktop environment's menu.

Comment: The machine is from the 1990s, and cannot boot into a GUI, all I see on tty7 (the X screen) is a cursor, with a black screen.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest finding a PS2 keyboard, as they're dirt cheap, and trying a lighter distribution.

Comment: Could I `dd` the cd to the hard drive, and modify `isolinux.cfg` to default to the "Install" option?